# “Parse Error : There is a issue parsing the package” while installing Android application"

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

My android application not working got Parse error on my mobile android version 2.3.6  But works on android version 4.4.x

Comment: please paste some code and logcat.

Comment: Is this really related to angular js or ionic? It seems you are asking about android.

Comment: It is belongs to android